# SWT Button setImage(null)

Tags: image, button, null, swt, jface

I want my `Button` not to resize when setting the image null.

Button is wrapped in a custom `ColorSelector` from **JFace**. [See here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/preference/ColorSelector.html).

I've made my own custom color selector, so that I can set a null image to the button.

e.g. *Background Color* is null here:

[image]

My solutions:

Set `GridData` to `SWT.FILL` internally.

Set `widthHint` or `minimumWidth`.

Draw a gradient rectangle on a 'default image', then set that image to the button. (remember, Cocoa buttons have a gradient, so this solution if for presenting the button like nothing's there)

But I don't like these. They seem like hardcore workarounds.

Comment: Well, what exactly do you expect? The button doesn't have an image or text to display, so the size computation for this widget will return the minimal size unless you force it to be larger by using `GridData` settings. The button behaves exactly like you would expect it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting a null-image, you may try to set a fully transparent image.